# Django Admin Detail Page Link to an External URL

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to link to a page OUTSIDE of my django admin side with the following code for a function that is added as as `read_only` field of my admin interface.

```py
    def website(self, preset):
        if preset.he_school.profile.admissions_url:
            return format_html(
                f"<a href='{preset.he_school.profile.url}'>Link</a>"
            )
```

The problem is I always get URLs of the resulting link with the path to this page prepended to the URL I actually want to send people to: `386/change/www.sc.edu/admissions` instead, I just want to send people to `www.sc.edu/admissions`

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `http://` to the front of the URL so the browser treats it as an absolute and not an internal/relative link.

```py
    def website(self, preset):
       if preset.he_school.profile.admissions_url:
          return format_html(
            f"<a href='http://{preset.he_school.profile.url}'>Link</a>"
          )
```